# Get all tasks under the specific iteration(match the conditions)?

Tags: java, rest, iteration, task, rally

I want to use Rally Rest Toolkit java to get all iterations between 2014-06-01 and 2014-06-08,then get all tasks under these iterations.How can I?

Any help would be great! Many Thanks!

Comment: Reading the documentation, start writing some code and try something would be good starts.

Answer (score 1):

To get tasks of iteration that falls within certain dates use this syntax:

```
taskRequest.setQueryFilter(new QueryFilter("Iteration.StartDate", ">=", "2014-06-01").and(new QueryFilter("Iteration.EndDate", "<=", "2014-06-08")));
```

and set workspace of the request:

```
taskRequest.setWorkspace("123456); //use your ObjectID
```

so that child iterations (from all projects in the workspace) with the same start and end dates are included in the results.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws URISyntaxException, IOException {

    String host = "https://rally1.rallydev.com";
    String username = "user@co.com";
    String password = "psw";
    String workspaceRef = "/workspace/12352608129"; 
    String applicationName = "ExampleFindTasks";

    RallyRestApi restApi = null;

    try{
        restApi = new RallyRestApi(
                new URI(host),
                username,
                password);
        restApi.setApplicationName(applicationName); 

        QueryRequest taskRequest = new QueryRequest("Task");
        taskRequest.setFetch(new Fetch("Name","FormattedID","Iteration","Project"));
        taskRequest.setLimit(1000);
        taskRequest.setScopedDown(true);
        taskRequest.setScopedUp(false);
        taskRequest.setWorkspace(workspaceRef);
        taskRequest.setQueryFilter(
                new QueryFilter("Iteration.StartDate", ">=", "2014-06-01").and(
                        new QueryFilter("Iteration.EndDate", "<=", "2014-06-08")));

        QueryResponse taskQueryResponse = restApi.query(taskRequest);
        int numberOfResults = taskQueryResponse.getTotalResultCount();
        System.out.println(numberOfResults);

        if(numberOfResults > 0){
            for (int i=0;i<numberOfResults;i++){
                JsonObject taskJsonObject = taskQueryResponse.getResults().get(i).getAsJsonObject();
                System.out.println("Name: " + taskJsonObject.get("Name") + " " + "FormattedID: " +
                taskJsonObject.get("FormattedID"));
                JsonElement iteration = taskJsonObject.get("Iteration");
                JsonElement project = taskJsonObject.get("Project");
                try{
                    JsonObject iterationObject = iteration.getAsJsonObject().getAsJsonObject();
                    JsonObject projectObject = project.getAsJsonObject().getAsJsonObject();
                    System.out.println(iterationObject.get("Name"));
                    System.out.println(projectObject.get("Name"));
                }
                catch (java.lang.IllegalStateException ise) {
                    System.out.println("ise");
                }
            }
        }
    }
    finally{
        if (restApi != null) {
            restApi.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much！O(∩_∩)O！If I want save what you parse on console to csv file，how should I do？